# Vertical and horizontal align of divs

Tags: css, css-float, css-position, vertical-alignment

Please expand the jsfiddle to see box in action, http://jsfiddle.net/5fp37/.
I want the blue border boxes to align side by side, but I dont want to mention a width to the boxes. 
This fiddle works ok but as soon as I remove the `width:400px`, both boxes get on top/bottom of each other. Any clue?

**dont want to specifiy width of any thing. board or box.** just a minimum width of box, because ther could be unkown number of boxes. and each would alight side by side

**Nor want the divs to change position when page is re sized. verticals always align vertically and horizontals always align horizontally** regardless of parent or child items / width.

Vertical boxes go side by side and horizontal ones go top/bottom of each other. Regardless of container size or number of their own children (task `div`s in this case)

It seems like impossible. Is there a way?

[image]

---

[image]

---

wanted to do this:

http://leankit.com/blog/2010/12/10-kanban-boards-leankit-kanban-style/

[image]
[image]

```
.board{
  display:block;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

  border: red solid thin;
  min-height:510px;

}

.box{
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: blue solid thin;
  min-height:500px;
  min-width:160;
  width:400px;

}

.box-virtical{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;

}

.box-horizontal{
  display:block;


}



.task{
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display:block;
  float: left;
  border: green solid thin;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
}






     <div class="board">
  <div class="box box-virtical">
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box box-virtical">
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
    <div class="task">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't hink that what you try to acheive is possible using float. The problem with floating elements is that they first of all take the width they need displaying their contents if you don't specify one. So your green boxes will be aligned first. It than checks if two green boxes can be floated next to each other.

What you might try is using display: table, table-row and table-cell. See my fiddle-update for the changes http://jsfiddle.net/5fp37/5/

Please check if the browser support is enough for you (no internet explorer 7 and below)

The benefit of it: it stretches automatically like every table and you can use vertical-align: middle inside of it for vertical alignment.

```
.board {
   display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.boardrow {
   display: table-row;
}

.box{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks and plus 1 for the lovely answer! I have edited my question and added more photos and a link in "wanted to do this:". Do you still think I need display:tables?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902138/vertical-and-horizontal-align-of-div-part2

Comment: yeah i would use display:table as it seems like the behaviour you are trying to create is pretty much the one of a table. just: it's a layout table and no semantically correct content table. as soon as you don't really know the width of your elements but want them to take the space you have it's a great way to do it.

Comment: @RiaElliger that's a really bad generalization. HTML and CSS is all about semantics and you are just wrong to say table is "bad"

Comment: Sorry, my comment could be missunderstood. I know that tables aren't bad at all. But to use tables in THIS context would be bad as it's a layout table, not a semantic table. I am totally pro tables if you want to display a semantically correct data table.

Answer (score 2):

Use flex-box.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fp37/6/)

```
.board{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

I used this [generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto)