# vertical and horizontal align of div - part2

Tags: css, css-float, css-position, css-tables

In reference to [Vertical and horizontal align of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900039/vertical-and-horizontal-align-of-divs)

and this new code http://jsfiddle.net/8B29k/2/

**Why the "box at bottom" not covering the full width?**

I do not want to us html colspan (cannot in this scenarios because boxes will be generated dynamically and I may self wont know how many are upside and downside of one box)

each box s independant of the boxes besides it or above/below it. thats now the case with tables. if there are 3 TR and 3 TD in each TR ,  i cannot make the middle  TR have just one TD and expand its width as equal to the other TRs (all TDs combined) . cant do that without colspan in html.     but in this scenario. I my self wont know the surrounding TDs.  so what is the solution for it?

This is the layout that I am trying to create:

[image]

```
.board{
  display:block;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

  border: red solid thin;
  /**min-height:510px;**/

}


.board-title{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:50px;
}

.board-body{

}

.box{

  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: blue solid thin;
  /**min-height:500px;**/
  min-width:160px;
  height:100%;



}

.box-title{

  width:100%;
  background-color:grey;
  font-size:50px;
}

.box-body{
  display:table-row;
}

.box-parent{


}

.box-vertical{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top:


    vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: blue solid thin;
  /**min-height:500px;**/
  min-width:160px;
  height:100%;
}

.box-horizontal{
  display:table-row;

    vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: blue solid thin;
  /**min-height:500px;**/
  min-width:160px;
  height:100%;
}



.task{
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display:block;
  float: left;
  border: green solid thin;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
}
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="board">
    <div class="board-title">board title- 
    </div>
    <div class="board-body">

        <div class="box-vertical">
            <div class="box-title">box1 title- 
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="box-vertical">
                      <div class="box-title">inner box title
                      </div>
                      <div class="box-body">
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                          <div class="task">
                          </div>
                      </div>   
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>






        <div class="box-vertical">
              <div class="box-title">box at side title- 
              </div>
              <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
              </div>   
        </div>





        <div class="box-horizontal">
              <div class="box-title">box at bottom - title
              </div>
              <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
                  <div class="task">
                  </div>
              </div>   
        </div>
















    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use HTML tables?

Comment: If this is the entirety of your HTML, it's because you're not closing `<div>` tags. This causes some elements to be placed inside others, rather than next to them. Tables would be much, much easier.

Comment: @trojansdestroy true, I edited. now a problem: Why the "box at bottom" not covering the full width?

Comment: Try removing `display:table-row` from .box-horizontal, why not take our advice and go with actual tables instead of trying to simulate them using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7brCZ/7/
http://jsfiddle.net/7brCZ/7/embedded/result/

[image]

```
.board{
  display:block;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

  border: red solid thin;
  /**min-height:510px;**/

}


.board-title{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:50px;
}

.board-body{

}

.box{

  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: blue solid thin;
  /**min-height:500px;**/
  min-width:160px;
  height:100%;



}

.box-title{

  width:100%;
  background-color:grey;
  font-size:50px;
}

.box-body{
  display:table;
}

.box-parent{


}

.box-vertical{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top:


    vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: blue solid thin;
  /**min-height:500px;**/
  min-width:160px;
  height:100%;
}

.box-horizontal{


    vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: blue solid thin;
  /**min-height:500px;**/
  min-width:160px;
  height:100%;
}



.task{
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display:block;
  float: left;
  border: green solid thin;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
}






    <div class="board">
        <div class="board-title">board
        </div>
        <div class="board-body">






            <div class="box-vertical">
                  <div class="box-title">box at virtical
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                  </div>   
            </div>



            <div class="box-vertical">
                  <div class="box-title">box at virtical
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                  </div>   
            </div>









            <div class="box-vertical">
                <div class="box-title">box virtical
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="box-vertical">
                          <div class="box-title">inner virtical box
                          </div>
                          <div class="box-body">
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                              <div class="task">
                              </div>
                          </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-vertical">
                          <div class="box-title">inner virtical box
                          </div>
                          <div class="box-body">





                            <div class="box-vertical">
                                  <div class="box-title">inner virtical box
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="box-body">
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-vertical">
                                  <div class="box-title">inner virtical box
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="box-body">
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="task">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>   
                            </div>






                          </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>






            <div class="box-vertical">
                  <div class="box-title">box at side
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                  </div>   
            </div>





            <div class="box-horizontal">
                  <div class="box-title">box at horizontal
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                  </div>   
            </div>



            <div class="box-horizontal">
                  <div class="box-title">box at horizontal
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                      <div class="task">
                      </div>
                  </div>   
            </div>


            <div class="box-horizontal">
                  <div class="box-title">box at horizontal
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-body">



                      <div class="box-vertical">
                        <div class="box-title">inner virtical box
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                      </div>
                      <div class="box-vertical">
                        <div class="box-title">inner virtical box
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                      </div>

                      <div class="box-vertical">
                        <div class="box-title">inner virtical box
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                            <div class="task">
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                      </div>





                  </div>   
            </div>





        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Is this what you were aiming for?